# Original title: Can't update or install packages Ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Unable to update or install packages on Ubuntu server 18.04. Internet service provider Rostelecom, We are sitting behind their proxy server and content filtering. And so that we can work normally with Ubuntu server 18.04, they ask us to provide update ports. sources.list isn't enough for them. Where can I see the list of ports ??? Thank you in advance! Regards, Oleg.

Comment: Please share the error output which you get while running `sudo apt-get update` . Ports are usually 80 and 443, so they should not blocked.

Comment: We are sitting behind a proxy server 10.0.35.52:3128, ports 80 and 443 are not blocked, it gives an error that it cannot connect through the addresses specified by sources.list. I need the IP addresses and port numbers of the Ubuntu update sites to be able to perform updates on my systems, since Rostelecom can only open certain ports for certain IP addresses, this is a requirement of their cyber security guards.